# Turn on MacBook with eject key or via USB

Tags: macbook-pro, power, eject

I had a problem with my MacBook Pro keyboard (mid 2010), and the power button stops working. Now, to turn on my MacBook I have to short the power pads.

In the new MacBooks with no optical drive, the power button is in the place of the eject button. My eject key is working, so I would like to change this key to "power button" in order to can turn on my laptop without have to open it and short the pads.. Is this possible?

Is there another way to do it? Maybe via USB that when you plug it send a turn on command?

Another way that I have thought is that Macbook turn itself on when plugged in.
I tried `sudo pmset -a acwake 1` but it doesn't work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Did you already do the SMC reset?
If not do it even twice or thrice (firmware can be suprisingly stubborn).
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Comment: The failure comes after liquid spill... so I don't think it works :(